# Make dolthub/dolthub-etl-jobs/tree/master/loaders/nvd use newer CVE scheme

Tags: go, github

I am trying to get some code to run which is here, on GitHub:

https://github.com/dolthub/dolthub-etl-jobs/tree/master/loaders/nvd

Once I've cloned the repo I run the `run.sh` script and it fails with the below:

```
./run.sh
1 synchronisation error:
        unexpected http response from "https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/json/cve/1.0/nvdcve-1.0-2002.meta" ("404 Not Found"): ""
cloning https://doltremoteapi.dolthub.com/Liquidata/NVD
```

For this to have a chance of working I need to change wherever this is referenced:

`https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/json/cve/1.0/nvdcve-1.0-20XX.meta`

to:

`https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/json/cve/1.1/nvdcve-1.1-20XX.meta`

The old reference is no longer valid.

However, it's impossible to see where the script is actually calling that URL from. Probably I do not know near enough about how go and GitHub hang together.

If I could figure it out, maybe I could just pull down the code and edit it manually once it was on my host or even create a fork with the new URL in it.

1. Find where the URL is actually coming from when I call `run.sh` which errors out almost immediately.
2. Make a change that reflects the valid one.

Comment: in main.go, line 147, you will find a clue: `schema.NVDCVEFeedJSON10`. Now you only have to find out, where that pretty literal is defined. Depending on your editor, you could try "go to definition".

Comment: Who voted this down... please comment so I can edit it if required.

Comment: @BitTickler Thanks, I can't find anything still... there is a reference to this: "github.com/facebookincubator/nvdtools/cvefeed/nvd/schema"
 "github.com/facebookincubator/nvdtools/providers/nvd" and withing nvdtools there are references to https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/json/cve/1.0/nvdcve-1.0-20XX.meta however that is only in older versions of that facebook repo, even they are up to date.. so it would have to be pointed at an older nvdtools facebook repo, again, I can't understand how I could verify or if that is an avenue worth pursuing

Comment: 1. `cd` into repository. run `grep -irl $WEBSITE_URL .` This should return the path(s) of any file(s) containing `$WEBSITEURL`
2. Paste the link you know to work in the file(s) found in step 1.

Comment: In loaders/nvd run `go get -u github.com/facebookincubator/nvdtools`. That should update the dependency (see go.mod in that same directory). You may have to remove the replace directive in go.mod first. I forget how go get behaves in the presence of replace directives.

Comment: @kendfss the output appears just to be from the README which is not actually run. Makes me think it is something remote... grep -irl 'nvdcve-1.0-2002'
nvdtools/cmd/nvdsync/README.md
.bash_history
go/pkg/mod/github.com/liquidata-inc/nvdtools@v0.1.4-0.20200529221554-e67111c0fff4/cmd/nvdsync/README.md

Comment: @Peter that does do something... upgrades it to v0.1.5. I still get the same error :-/ Do I need to refresh / delete / reload something before I run run.sh again? -->    go get -u github.com/facebookincubator/nvdtools
go: upgraded github.com/facebookincubator/nvdtools v0.1.3 => v0.1.5
root@host:~# ./run.sh
1 synchronisation error:
        unexpected http response from "https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/json/cve/1.0/nvdcve-1.0-2002.meta" ("404 Not Found"): ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: Replace 4 by 6 in line 44 of `main.go`.

`go.mod` from https://github.com/dolthub/dolthub-etl-jobs/tree/master/loaders/nvd
requires `github.com/facebookincubator/nvdtools` but replaces this by `github.com/liquidata-inc/nvdtools` which redirects to `github.com/dolthub/nvdtools` which is an archived repo(!) (cf. https://github.com/dolthub/dolthub-etl-jobs/blob/d858a2433f68d72dc643e26085a5a0c44edbb85c/loaders/nvd/go.mod#L5-L7).

Supported CVE feeds of `dolthub/nvdtools` are defined here: https://github.com/dolthub/nvdtools/blob/e67111c0fff487cc15cd2ba32668141622cf9c63/providers/nvd/cve.go#L44-L53

`cve10jsonGz` is `4`, `cve11jsonGz` is `6`

`main.go` sets the CVE feed here: https://github.com/dolthub/dolthub-etl-jobs/blob/d858a2433f68d72dc643e26085a5a0c44edbb85c/loaders/nvd/main.go#L43.

Change it from `4` to `6`.

I didn't test the rest of `run.sh`, but at least the problem you're mentioning in your question should be solved.